# Starting a love interest in Mass Effect 2 from a Mass Effect 1 save file

Tags: mass-effect-2

I may have skipped a point or convo or something. But I currently have a (female) Shepard file from Mass Effect 1 and I'm playing Mass Effect 2. In the original Mass Effect, the Shepard's love interest was Liara T'Soni.

However, I'd like to move on to another possible love interest in Kelly Chambers. (Wanted to see the dance scene.) But something is, wrong, I think.

I talked with Kelly and told her she can feed my fish when I'm away and even had the dinner scene. But, I can't go further than that. I know I'm supposed to be able to call her to the loft. but that's not showing up in the file.

Did I skip a dialogue somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call Kelly up to your cabin until *after* you travel through the Omega 4 relay.

***SPOILERS***

> Even then, you can only call her up if you manage to save her from the Collectors by doing only one mission after you get the Reaper IFF (which will likely be Legion's loyalty mission), otherwise she will die.